# Where can I download synaptics touchpad drivers?

Tags: 11.04, drivers, touchpad, synaptics

Synaptics touchpad is not working on my friend's laptop.

Here is the result of `xinput list`:

- http://paste.ubuntu.com/611380/

I think the touchpad is not detected at all, he's using the laptop with a mouse right now so which is shown as `OPTICAL MOUSE` in the xinput list result.

Where can I download synaptics drivers for Ubuntu Natty?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried "gpointing-device-settings" it in your synaptic package manager it what i use for my acer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check in Synaptic (sounds similar but is the package manager of Ubuntu; in 11.04 use the dash and type syn and it will show up in other versions choose system, admin, synaptic) if synaptics driver for xorg is installed?